# Error 403 SendSecurityCheck Genexus 15 U4 - Log Tomcat

Tags: genexus

Actualmente presento un problema en Genexus 15 U4  que se ve reflejado en el .txt de errores del Tomcat, al cargar un WebPanel sea a través de K2BTools o no,  y donde este realiza una consulta a la Base de Datos (ORACLE)  se escribe en el log de errores del Tomcat mensajes por los registros que se muestran, y me manda un error de SendSecurityCheck.

[image: Error SendSecurityCheck]

Tambien se presentan mensajes de Error 403
[image: Error 403]

¿A que se debe estos errores? o que necesitaría configurar en la KB para evitar errores de este tipo . He investigado y no he encontrado mucha información de este problema en particular. Adicionalmente estoy usando la K2BTools10.0.1 .Cualquier ayuda al respecto seria de mucha importancia. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El primer grupo de mensajes no es un error, está mostrando los valores que se identificaron como fijos. Estos valores no pueden cambiar, por ejemplo corresponden a parámetros de tipo *in* o son atributos en un WebPanel.

En caso que cambien se considera que hubo manipulación del estado de la aplicación por fuera de su uso esperado (i.e. un ataque), y ahí aparece el segundo mensaje 403 en el log.

Desde la versión V15U6, el primer grupo de mensajes solo se registran si usas el gxclassd.jar (modalidad de *debug*).

En *upgrades* más recientes al que estás usando hubo mejoras a este mecanismo que evita casos de falsos positivos. Si puedes pasarte al V15U6 podría estar solucionado. Si eso no lo resuelve, otra opción puede ser comunicarte con soporte para ver más en detalle el caso.